# cql_filter for fid

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, cql-filter

when i run this code:

```
http://****/geoserver/Kaski/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Kaski:PIN&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=json&cql_filter=(fid=97)
```

i got this error :

```
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd">
<ServiceException code="InvalidParameterValue">Illegal property name: fid</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

but i need to filter with fid. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 5):

```
http://***/geoserver/Kaski/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Kaski:PIN&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=json&featureID=97
```

not use cql_fiter it is working. thanks anyway